# Google Domain Api Access Type Public Not Working

Tags: google-plus, google-domain-api

I have issue connect with type access, after post with help google domain api on google plus page, top part on my post I can't see "public" only private, domain or show only for me, how can I resolve it ?
I spoke with google support he told me what on my console all good.

Scopes
http://i.prntscr.com/IVs4E5yHQLi30sYazCaKNw.png
Get Token 
http://i.prntscr.com/afhAgxzgRz_AflG3fkLgrA.png
How I see on top my post
http://i.prntscr.com/VqeWNM9DS46SyHsQQS3XHw.png

```
    $plusDomain = new \Google_Service_PlusDomains($client);
    $activity = new \Google_Service_PlusDomains_Activity();
    $obj = new \Google_Service_PlusDomains_ActivityObject();

    $access = new \Google_Service_PlusDomains_Acl();
    $access_type = new \Google_Service_PlusDomains_PlusDomainsAclentryResource();
    $comment = 'new comments';

        $me = $plusDomain->people->get('me');
        $userId = $me->id;

        $obj->setContent($comment);
        $access->setDomainRestricted(true);
        $access_type->setType('public');
        $access->setItems(array($access_type));

        $activity->setObject($obj);
        $activity->setAccess($access);

        $plusDomain->activities->insert($userId, $activity);
```

Comment: Thats what google+ domains does it lets you post to your domain account everyone with access to your domains account will be able to see the posts.

Comment: Thank you for answer, so my post can see only my company people ?

Comment: yup anyone with access to the domain account should be able to see it

Comment: post can see only people my company.
$access->setDomainRestricted(true);
I think on this line "true" must be 'false'
but when I changed I get this error
http://i.prntscr.com/sup8B9qqTR6lSFqG2Fd1LQ.png

Comment: You can't post content public on general google+. You can only post content that is restricted to your domain.

Comment: Thank you Abraham for answer, you are help me, but I have questions:
1) Is there a method in the entire system that would give me access to publish to google + as public, maybe there is a paid method?
2) If not: how can I register my customers under my domain, how can I give them access to watch my posts?